# Error while inserting a value in Python tkinter Entry box

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I was making a program that takes values from a user and then appends that values to a db file using sqlite3 database. But while inserting the value to entry box a strange error occured.

```
import sqlite3,time,datetime
from Tkinter import *

def create_table():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("medicaps.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE data(NAME TEXT,ENROLLMENT_NUMBER INT,MARKS INT,GRADE TEXT,UNIXTIME REAL ,DATETIME TEXT)")



class Application(Frame):


    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()



    def create_widgets(self):
        Label(self,text = "Welcome to the database entry program.").grid(row = 0,column = 0,columnspan = 2,sticky = W)

        Label(self,text = "Name : ").grid(row = 1,column = 0,sticky = W)
        Label(self,text = "Enrollment number : ").grid(row = 2,column = 0,sticky = W)
        Label(self,text = "Marks : ").grid(row = 3,column = 0,sticky = W)
        Label(self,text = "Grade : ").grid(row = 4,column = 0,sticky = W)

        self.name = Entry(self)
        self.name.grid(row = 1,column = 1)

        self.number = Entry(self)
        self.number.grid(row = 2,column = 1)

        self.marks = Entry(self)
        self.marks.grid(row = 3,column = 1)

        self.grade = Entry(self)
        self.grade.grid(row = 4,column = 1)

        self.text = Text(self,width = 35,height = 25,wrap = WORD)
        self.text.grid(row = 6,column = 0,columnspan = 2,sticky = W)

        Button(self,text = "Submit",command = self.reveal).grid(row = 5,column = 0,sticky = W)

    def reveal(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect("medicaps.db")
        c = conn.cursor()
        unix = time.time()
        date = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(time.time())).strftime("%Y-%M-%d %H:%M:%S"))
        name = self.name.get()
        number = self.number.get()
        marks = self.marks.get()
        grade = self.grade.get()

        self.text.insert(0.0,"yoyo")

        try:
            number = int(number)
        except(ValueError):
            error_n = "Invalid Input"
            self.number.insert(0.0,error_n)

        try:
            marks = int(number)
        except(ValueError):
            error_m = "Invalid Input"
            self.marks.insert(0.0,error_m)

        c.execute("INSERT INTO data(NAME,ENROLLMENT_NUMBER,MARKS,GRADE,UNIXTIME,DATETIME) VALUES = (?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                  (name,number,marks,grade,unix,date))
        conn.commit()
        message = "Value appended successfully"
        self.text.delete(0.0,END)





root = Tk()


root.title("Dataentry")
root.geometry("500x750")

frame = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

The following error was raised

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\sahib navlani\Desktop\New folder\vdsf.py", line 62, in reveal
    self.number.insert(0.0,error_n)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2517, in insert
    self.tk.call(self._w, 'insert', index, string)
  TclError: bad entry index "0.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you exactly what the problem is. `0.0` is a bad index. `self.number` is an `Entry`, and indexes are integers starting at zero.

You also try to use this same index for a `Text` widget, which is also invalid. `Text` widget indexes are a string (*not* floating point number) of the form *<line>.<char>*, where *<line>* is the number number starting at `1` (one) and *<char>* starts with `0` (zero). Thus, the very first index of a `Text` widget is the string `"1.0"`.

Comment: Trying this command on text box works absolutely fine. And as far I know 0.0 represents the rows and columns inside a text box

Comment: @SahibNavlani: "rows and columns" isn't entirely accurate for a `Text` widet, but it's close. If you have a fixed width font you can consider the character positions to be columns. `0.0` works, but only because Tkinter is a bit forgiving. `-100.00` also works, but the fact remains, the first character is officially `"1.0"`.

Answer (score 0):

Read the traceback in relation to your code.  self.number is an Entry().  An entry index is defined in this [fine reference](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/entry.html#entry-index), which I recommend that people bookmark.  Since Entry widgets contain a single line of text, an index for such is single int.  Try `0` instead of `0.0`.